# NSDateFormatter dateFromString issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having a trouble converting NSString to NSDate.

I have a date string like 'Mon Dec 13 14:55:05 +0800 2010', here is my code:

```
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mon Dec 13 14:55:05 +0800 2010"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Odd, It works fine yesterday, but I'm getting nil now.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

24-hour notation needs an HH string representation instead of hh so you should have

```
@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"
```